# Video download problem with fluter Web when crossOriginIsolated=true

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, cors

I'm working on a flutter application manipulating images and videos. For video re-encoding I use ffmpeg_wasm and shared buffer which requires crossOriginIsolated.
Video encoding works well, downloading and image display also works, however downloading videos from Firebase storage is blocked by the browser because **Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy is not-set** causing error 206.

To solve this issue i suppose firebase storage should set this header but i don't hunderstand why picture work

[Picture of request header using Image.network(myURL)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CULW.png)

[And video using video_player: ^2.7.1 VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(myURL)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4ber.png)

I note Sec-Fetch-Mode is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of work i found html video tag work if i add crossorigin="anonymous" proprety.

So i add this propery in video_player_web.dart file in the lib folder of the plug in

```
final VideoElement videoElement = VideoElement()
      ..id = 'videoElement-$textureId'
      ..src = uri
      ..crossOrigin = "anonymous"
      ..style.border = 'none'
      ..style.height = '100%'
      ..style.width = '100%';
```

and it work